# Bread with no salt

Tags: bread, salt, yeast

I've been doing a lot of yeast bread baking as of late and I got to wondering what the salt in the bread was for.  Upon doing some research it turns out (aside from perhaps some flavor) the purpose is to "Control" the yeast during the rise.  This got me to wondering if it was possible to make a yeast bread with no salt at all.  My first attempt was met with defeat, and upon some more experimentation I was able to get the salt down 75% with success.  Its the last 25% that alludes me.

Is it possible to make a yeast bread with no salt?

Comment: What is the problem/symptoms if you leave out all the salt? I have done it (leaving all the salt out) frequently, and in general I find the result good enough. Also, how much yeast do you start with? If you are relying on salt to inhibit yeast growth, maybe you are just using too much yeast?

Comment: What I usually run into is the top of the load collapsing in on itself.  The recipe I am using calls for 2 teaspoons of yeast.

Comment: "2 teaspoons" doesn't say much. What is important is the ratio of yeast to flour by weight, with usable amounts ranging from 0.5% to 10% of the flour weight in raw yeast (divide by 3 for active dry). Numbers at the edge of the interval are difficult to work with, 2% for lean and 3% for enriched breads are common, maybe 1% more for quick rises. (2% means 2 gram yeast to 100 g flour).

Comment: @rumtscho thanks!  I'll have to do some more experimenting later today.

Comment: Look up [Tuscan Bread](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/tuscan-bread-pane-toscano-recipe) which is traditionally made with no salt.

Comment: I normally use about 1/3 the salt in the breadmaker recipes I make (most frequently pizza dough or olive bread where it's not needed for flavour).  I haven't found that I need to reduce the liquid (though I might try next time) but I do reduce the sugar to about 2/3 of the original value - sugar is a very accessible source of energy for the yeast and gets it going fast - my theory was that it was too fast.  Not an answer as I haven't tried removing the salt completely, but perhaps somewhere else to look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make a bread without salt, you will have to make the dough dryer as well. Salt (for lack of a better word) competes with gluten and yeast for moisture. Without the salt, the yeast will work a bit faster (this effect isn't that pronounced) and the gluten will be very soft. The effect on the gluten usually causes loaves without salt to fall flat as the gluten is overly extensible but not very elastic. This could be part of why your loaves are collapsing, as without salt it is very hard to maintain the tension of the outer gluten sheath.

As SAJ14SAJ points out, the lack of salt will make the bread taste very "flat". While there are breads traditionally made without salt, they are usually served with very flavorful accompaniments like olives and sardines. Depending on what you're using the bread for, I'd suggest using an enriched dough as the added flavor of eggs, butter, and/or sugar will also help to cover the lack of salt.

Edited to add links to a [couple](http://jayonbread.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/more-thoughts-on-dough-development/) of [articles](http://www.bakersjournal.com/content/view/916/38/) describing salt's effects on dough and one on [salt taste](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK50958/) in general.

Answer (score 10):

I have been successfully making yeast bread without salt for more than 3 decades.

There's really no particular difficulty in doing so.

If you are habituated to excessive salt levels, as in virtually all commercial processed foods, I suppose you might find that it tastes funny, but if you stop eating too much salt for a couple of weeks you'll discover that you don't "need" salt to make food (including yeast bread) have flavor.

Comment: Seconded, good one

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, you can reduce the amount of salt more (up to 100%) in white bread than you can wholemeal/brown. Less salt in a wholemeal loaf and it doesn't seem to rise as much, and the consistency is different (I have not tried varying the amount of moisture as suggested above). In a white loaf, I can't see much difference in this regard.

As has been said above, salt does play a role in the process, but also the taste. I don't like things very salty, so tried leaving it out. I sometimes make a white French loaf with zero salt, and it's fine, although does taste very different. If you are putting e.g. salted butter on it, this may not be so pronounced. I generally reduce the amount by 50-75% for white, and 25-50% for brown/wholemeal. But if you are serving it with something sweet, saltiness can complement this well (IMO).

To prove it, see below photo of a white French loaf made in an automatic breadmaker with zero salt (just dried yeast, flour and water).

[image: A white French loaf made with no salt, which looks similar to a 'normal' loaf]

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible to make bread without salt.     You would adjust the initial quantity of yeast and proofing times to get the desired outcome (it sounds like your loaves are over-proofing).

The thing is, it would taste terrible.   Enhancing the flavor is the more important role of salt in bread, not just governing the growth rate of the yeast.

Comment: I disagree with the "terrible" part. The enhancement in taste exists, but it is small, and while I can notice it, often I don't miss it when I decide to go without.

Comment: @rumtscho Okay, awful, flat, bland, boring, tasteless, dead, lifeless, icky.... :-) :-)

Comment: Certain Italian breads have no salt. The flavour comes from a long slow prove and really, really good olive oil for dipping :)

Comment: I would think its very possible to make a flavorful bread with no salt.  Perhaps by adding something else to make up for it not being there as @ElendilTheTall suggests.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Those would definitely be a fringe case, of which i have not previously heard :-)   I stand by bland and boring for bread without salt.  Prisons do that to punish prisoners for whom there is no other punishment.

Comment: I conclude that while salt certainly changes the taste, it is a matter of personal preference if you find this change necessary or optional. I have never met somebody who has found it unwanted, so bakers are on the safe side when adding it. And sure, this answer is right that taste is the main reason for salt in bread.

Comment: Tuscan bread is very bland on it's own but has a really good open texture. It's sort of like chewable water.

Answer (score 1):

I make my machine bread totally saltless and usually add grains...seeds etc. according to taste and availability.

It is very important to reduce the amount of yeast!!!
 I only add 2/3 of the yeast in the recipe and add a 1/4 teaspoon of bread improver and a bit of brown sugar and oil, of course.

It tastes great as is when just baked. Once it is cool, I toast it and tastes great again because the heat develops the grains/seeds taste.

As with everything else: adjustment and compromise.

Answer (score -2):

Use **French's NoSalt** instead of salt.

Comment: Now, how would that product interact with the yeast? OP asked not for substitutions, but whether leaving out the salt would influence the outcome. Welcome to the site, btw!

Comment: This is generally marketed as a salt substitute for seasoning, it'd be nice if you could expand your answer with information about its properties in baking. FYI for everyone else: This product is Potassium Chloride.

Comment: Which, if you're on a salt-restricted diet, it may be that you're also taking a high blood pressure medicine. Since potassium chloride interacts negatively with that, and you can't use this as a substitute.